# From System.in get and use the number of the desired item

Tags: java

I got some classes like `UniversityDepartment` & `PolytechnicDepartment` these 2 classes extends `AcademicDepartment` class. And the problem want me to do this. The `AcademicDepartment` can have pre-graduate program & after-graduate program. And the departments will be 2 `University` & `Polytechnic`. For a department to be polytechnic or University depending on the number of labs that have in pre-graduate program. So if we are in pre-graduate or after-graduate program i think the user must type it from keyboard and if we are in pre-graduate we also must be asked how many labs we got to see if we are in polytechnic or university. So how i will do this? I will give you an example of my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class  AcademicDepartment {
    private String names;
    private String labs;
    private int teachers;
    private int graduates;
    // private boolean studies;

    public void infostudies() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("Enter the department you want."
            + "Press 1 for pre-graduate program  or 2 for after-graduate program" );  
        String studies = "";  
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));  
        studies = br.readLine(); 

        if (studies == 1){
            System.out.println("You are in pre-graduate program");
            System.out.println("Enter the number of labs");
            String labs = ""; 
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            labs = br1.readLine();

            if (labs > 5){
                System.out.println("The department is polytechnic");
            }
        }        

        if (labs < 5 ){
            System.out.println("The department is University");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number try again");
        }
    }    

    public AcademicDepartment(String names,String labs,int teachers,int graduates){
        names = new String(names);
        this.labs = labs;
        this.teachers = teachers;
        this.graduates = graduates;
    }

    public void printdepartmentinfo(){
        System.out.println("The names are:" + names);
        System.out.println("The labs are:" + labs);
        System.out.println("The GRADUATES are:" + graduates);
        System.out.println("The teachers are:" + teachers);   
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what's your question? How to do *what* exactly? Since it seems like your example code is already reading some sort of user input. It's not very clear what you're stuck on.

Comment: Yes, as what Millimoose said, seems like you already have the basic logical structure implemented already. What precisely are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of unfortunate things about the code.

One problem is that you're comparing String variables `studies` and `labs` with integer literals. That is not permitted by the compiler. Normally one would either compare a String variable (using `String.equals`) with a String literal, or else attempt to interpret the String variable using `Integer.parseInt` before comparing with an integer.

Another problem is that some variables local to method `infostudies` have the same names as fields of class `AcademicDepartment`. That's permitted, but it's needlessly confusing.

For an example, you'll deal with variable `studies`, but I'll show you what I mean with regard to variable `labs`.

Don't do this:

```
public class AcademicDepartment {
    ...
    public void infostudies() throws IOException {
        ...
        if (studies == 1) {
            ...
            String labs = "";
            ...
            if (labs > 5){ // Compare String with int? Won't compile!
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
        if (labs < 5) { // Can't see the "labs" defined above!
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Do this:

```
public class AcademicDepartment {
    ...
    public void infostudies() throws IOException {
        ...
        if (studies == 1) {
            ...
            String labs = "";
            ...
            try {
                   int labCount = Integer.parseInt(labs);
                   if (labCount > 5) {
                       System.out.println("The department is polytechnic");
                   } else {
                       System.out.println("The department is University");
                   }
            } catch (NumberFormatException formatErr) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, couldn't understand your number of labs.");
            }
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u please explain me with code how to do this cause i am begginer and confused.. :/Thanks for your time.